# eonasdan datetimepicker, on change event triggered on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add ng-change to input which runs datetimepicker but it triggers on change function on page load. below is the code

```
<input datetimepicker ng-model="startDate" 
       ng-change="testFunction()" 
       options="cOptions" 
       placeholder="Select Date"/>
```

any idea how to prevent this ?

edit:

```
$scope.testFunction = testFunction;
function testFunction(){
    console.log('on change')
}

loadData();

function loadData(){
  //this is where startDate is set
}
```

Comment: Are you setting its value in controller on load? What is initial value you see in that input field?

Comment: @Shantanu I am getting value from DB on page load

Comment: Try adding `ng-if="startDate"` to it, and save the value to `$scope.startDate` only when you have the data back from the server

Comment: @AlonEitan it does not work

Comment: @user1751287 So you're saying that you don't have something like ` $scope.startDate = new Date();` anywhere outside `loadData()` and that you also added `ng-if="startDate"` to the element in the view, and it still trigger it?

Comment: @AlonEitan yes, it only gets set in that function

Comment: @AlonEitan trying to debug to see if it get's undefined from somewhere

Comment: @user1751287 If the answer below don't work, try binding the value to the view, once with one-time binding and another with 2way binding: `<div ng-bind="::startDate | date"></div><div ng-bind="startDate | date"></div>` this will show you the differences that are causing the ngChnage function to trigger

Comment: @AlonEitan it looks like different date format is causing this

Comment: @AlonEitan I have no idea how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Hi the change in input field where you're using the directive is triggered by the plugin, it's explicitly setting it to null. So you can have the validation like until input field in filled don't execute logic you written on ng-change function. There're two ways to do that:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" datetimepicker ng-model="vm.date" options="vm.options" 
    ng-change="vm.date && vm.changed()"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
    </span></span>
</div>
```

Now here ng-change will not trigger until something you inserted in the field. So onload it'll not triggered. 
Other way is like instead of anding this scope variable with its ng-change function, you can check in that function if the value is null or not. If it's non-null then only run the implementation written on ng-change.

Here's plunker showing both conditions:
http://plnkr.co/edit/uCf2vpmoYIYzxTjmFVcX?p=preview

Update: If you're editing value onload but still you don't want to execute implementation you written on ng-change then have separate variable, toggle its value on first ng-change, which's triggering automatically because of directive, next change onwards your ng-change function will run.
http://plnkr.co/edit/FogYzmDBd1gIolvjP7yl?p=preview

Comment: I dont see that you filled dates on page load

Comment: Sorry about previous comment. I was meaning like ng-change="testunction()" In controller have variable vm.isFirstLoad = true; And in testFunction have if condition like if(!vm.isFirstLoad) {..} then after it make vm.isFirstLoad = false; It should also work